# Why are SVG background images breaking when composite files enabled in dotnetnuke?

Tags: css, .net, svg, dotnetnuke

The site I'm working on uses a compressed SVG image as the background image for a button in a dotnetnuke site. The DNN version is 07.00.00 (1586). The css looks like this:

```
a.primaryButton {
     background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]);
}
```

NOTE: I've used [data] here instead of the actual compressed file.

When I enable composite files in Host -> Host Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Client Resource Management and check off Minify CSS and Minify JS the above background image changes to:

```
a.primaryButton {
     background: url(https://mydevsite.com/DependencyHandler.axd/image/svg+xml;base64,[data]);
}
```

Once this happens the SVG background image no longer appears. My initial thought is that there is an issue trying to compress an already compressed SVG. If I copy and paste the url into the browser I get a 400 invalid request response. Why would the SVG background image be invalid after enabling composite files in DNN?

#### Update

After thinking about this some more, it really does not make sense for the DNN composite file handler to replace `data:` in the code above with `https://mydevsite.com/DependencyHandler.axd` so a follow-up question is, how do I prevent the DNN composite file functionality from trying to compress SVG files used as background images in the css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke's [Client Resource Management Framework](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx) is the component which manages CSS files, and processes them to make sure resources are served via its `DependencyHandler.axd` endpoint.

However, there was a bug in that component regarding data URIs, like you're using here, which shouldn't be served via the Dependency Handler.  That bug was [fixed in DNN 7.0.5](http://support.dotnetnuke.com/project/DNN/2/item/21584).